# How can I work around hidesBottomBarWhenPushed acting weird with the iOS 6 SDK?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I ran into the same problem described in [this OpenRadar issue](http://www.openradar.me/14670329). As stated there:

> Summary: The hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property of UIViewController
>   doesn't work as expected for apps built with iOS 6 SDK (not beta SDKs
>   for iOS 7). The animation is weird when hiding the bottom bar (e.g. a
>   tab bar).
>
> Steps to Reproduce:
>
> 1. Create a new project with the TabBar template in Xcode 4. Add a UINavigationController to the FirstViewController. Add a button on the
>      FirstViewController and set its action to push a new view controller.
>      (please see the sample code attached)
> 2. Run the demo on an iOS 7 beta 5 device.
> 3. Press the button, back from the UINavigationController, pay attention to the animated view transitions.
>
> Expected Results: The animation works exactly the same as on an iOS 6
>   device.
>
> Actual Results: The animation looks weird. The FirstViewController is
>   sliding down from the bottom.
>
> Sample code: http://cl.ly/QgZZ

Is there any way to fix or work around this when building with the iOS 6 SDK?

Comment: facing the same issue in iOS 7 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue definitely exists. I did some investigation and found out what's causing it. When pushing a view controller with `UINavigationController`, you view controller's view is contained in a `UIViewControllerWrapperView`, which a private Apple's view managed by the `UINavigationController`. When the transition animation is about to occur and the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` is set to YES, this `UIViewControllerWrapperView` is being animated with wrong `position` for the Y axis, so the solution is just to overwrite this behaviour and give correct values for the animation. Here's the code:

```
//Declare a property
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldFixAnimation;

...

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

#ifndef __IPHONE_7_0 //If this constant is not defined then we probably build against lower SDK and we should do the fix
    if (self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed && [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7 && animated && self.navigationController) {
        self.shouldFixAnimation = YES;
    }
#endif

}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

#ifndef __IPHONE_7_0
    if(self.shouldFixAnimation) {
        self.shouldFixAnimation = NO;
        CABasicAnimation *basic = (CABasicAnimation *)[self.view.superview.layer animationForKey:@"position"]; //The superview is this UIViewControllerWrapperView

        //Just in case for future changes from Apple
        if(!basic || ![basic isKindOfClass:[CABasicAnimation class]]) 
            return;

        if(![basic.fromValue isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
            return;

        CABasicAnimation *animation = [basic mutableCopy];

        CGPoint point = [basic.fromValue CGPointValue];

        point.y = self.view.superview.layer.position.y;

        animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];

        [self.view.superview.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"position"];
        [self.view.superview.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
    }
#endif

}
```

Comment: It is working like a charm on Push !! but now facing issue on poping back :(

Comment: You can do it for the controller that initiates the push, also. Just remove the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` check in the if. Adjust it by your needs.

Comment: You can put both, the one that is pushed and the one that pushes. For the one that pushes just make sure to remove the check for `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` if it doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

In My Case, I had `TabBarViewController` with `UINavigationController` in each tabs & faced similar issue.
I used,

```
nextScreen.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
pushViewToCentralNavigationController(nextScreen)
```

It works fine when nextScreen is UITableViewController subclass & applied auto layout. 
But, It does not work fine when `nextScreen` is `UIViewController`. I found it depends on `nextScreen` auto layout constraints.

So I just updated my currentScreen with this code -

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

    }
```

In this way you can achieve desired outcome but its not good way to achieve it.

Hope it helps.