# Black flashes in iOS App Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

So I've been getting these black flashes when I segue from one view controller to another in my app. I don't understand what causes this.

[image: Notice the black flashes in the upper right hand corner behind the navigation bar]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dark shadow on navigation bar during segue transition after upgrading to Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413193/dark-shadow-on-navigation-bar-during-segue-transition-after-upgrading-to-xcode-5)

Comment: can you give the snapshot of your iPhone's home screen

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me post images directly yet, but the link in the question shows it in a gif.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you navigation controller's view backgroundColor is black. Either set it to your desired color, probably white:

```
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

or set your view controllers to extend edges, so the view of your view controller extends all the way under the navigation bar:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = .all // or .top
```

Comment: Great! That first one worked for me! Thanks a million!

Comment: The second one helped with a white gap flickering in the navigation bar. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the view hierarchy is a view with a black background. Use the view debugger in Xcode to find it, but it could possibly be your window or the navigation controller's view.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that