# a issue about hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TheElements/index.html

I find that when I push or pop a controller, the animation is weird.

[How can I work around hidesBottomBarWhenPushed acting weird with the iOS 6 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813910/how-can-i-work-around-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-acting-weird-with-the-ios-6-sdk)

Using the way above, when I pop a controller, the pushed controller would disappear directly.
How should I solve it? thanks.