# iOS7/8 translucent navigationBar top right corner of the black

Tags: ios, navigationbar

iOS8／iphone

When setting

```
navigationbar.translucent = yes;
```

If also set

```
blueVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = yes;
```

push `ViewController`, `navigationbar` right corner displays a black.

Test Results：

Black areas are `UIWindow` by default. I changed the `UIWindow` background color to white and that fixed the issue. But this just looks better, does not completely resolved.

[image]

=======================

[iOS7 strange animation when using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516046/ios7-strange-animation-when-using-hidesbottombarwhenpushed)

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
```

This approach will lead to push the process tabbar disappear. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details to your problem and ask a specific question so that the community can help you

Comment: Have you tried to see the `Debug View Hierarchy` to look for something wrong under your navigation bar ?

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @vicefava self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

And I thought it is similar to this post:[Dark shadow on navigation bar during segue transition after upgrading to Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413193/dark-shadow-on-navigation-bar-during-segue-transition-after-upgrading-to-xcode-5/22473381#22473381)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've encountered the same problem and your suggestion solved it. Are there any drawbacks?