# UITabBarController: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed weird animation

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that is part of a `UITabBarController`.
When I use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property, the animation is weird.

Storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

Why does the animation become so strange?

Comment: Kindly develop on `weird`, and replace this word by a clear description.

Comment: Answered Here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/39145532/2564720

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide tabbar in viewdiddisapper in first controller

Answer (score 0):

uncheck `translucent` property in tabbar